# Which meta-learning algorithms are well-suited for "many-shot learning" scenarios, where the target training set is large?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, domain-adaptation, meta-learning, maml

Much of the meta-learning literature deals with the few-shot learning problem of using data from a diverse set of "source" tasks (the meta-dataset) in order to train a model that can quickly learn how to solve a new, previously unseen "target" task. Here quickly means that the training set for the target task is very small (i.e., one with only a few labeled samples from).

I am facing a "many-shot" meta-learning problem, in which the main limitation is not the amount of training data for the target task, but rather very stringent accuracy requirements. If I'm fine-tuning a "vanilla" pre-trained model on my target task (one which was trained using ERM on the entire meta-dataset of source tasks), I need a target dataset of ~10M samples to reach the required accuracy specifications. My goal is to reach the same, or nearly the same, accuracy, with 1-2 orders of magnitude fewer labeled training samples (so ~100K or 1M target samples). If it helps, I also have a nearly unlimited supply of unlabeled samples from the target task. To achieve this goal, I have of course a (labeled) meta-dataset of many similar tasks.

In other words, while few-shot meta-learning algorithms deal (informally speaking) with the "maxmin" problem of first minimizing the target dataset size (number of shots) then maximizing accuracy, I'm facing the "minmax" problem of first maximizing the accuracy then minimizing the dataset size without hurting the performance too much.

I was not able to find any references that deal with this "many-shot meta-learning" scenario. So my questions:

1. Which meta-learning approaches would be well-suited to deal with this scenario?
2. Do you know of references to works that have studied this scenario?

Comment: Maybe you would get more responses if you edit your post to include info on your real applied problem?

Comment: Thanks very much for the suggestion! I can't provide the exact details of my problem, but I'll try to clarify my question. I'm faced with repeated (deep learning) regression tasks, where the data for each task comes from a somewhat different source. When I get data from a new source, I can have some of it labeled and use it to fine-tune a model trained on earlier sources. The accuracy I need requires ~10M labelled samples for fine tuning. I'd like to use meta-learning to achieve the same accuracy with 1-2 orders of magnitude less data, as labeling is expensive. Does this clarify my question?